# How can I create relationships in multiple tables on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, database-design

I'm new to rails and learning relationship between tables. This is what I want to create. Users wont be able to post into classes or videos just add them to their table.

example: 
I'm a student and I sign up for a user account. Then I choose the classes I want HTML and CSS. And then I'm only able to watch the videos inside those classes.

```
Users->classes->videos

(USERS)
username
password
classes - signs up for multiple classes

(classes)
HTML
CSS
Javascript
PHP

(inside of each class theres videos)
video1
video2
video3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship should be like `has_many`

```
User.rb
 has_many :classes
 has_many :videos, through: classes

Class.rb
 has_many :videos
 belongs_to :user

Video.rb
 belongs_to :class
 belongs_to :user
```

To apply this associations automatically you can use nested form structure

Here is link for that.

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised?view=comments

Thanks

Comment: Now when I do this does this create the relationship automatically meaning does it add userid, videoid, classesid to the table once I add that code to the model?

Comment: Updated my answers. Visit the link you will get complete idea. Thanks